# Prevent Delete Statement in SQL if criteria is not met

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

My scenario is: I have two tables in SQL one is Header and one is Detail. When a record is deleted in the Header I want to delete the Detail for the record as well. I'm doing some checking first before I actually delete the Detail.

My issue is that I'm joining the Header table based on the record being deleted when I do my checking, unfortunately when I do this the Header has been deleted already by the user's statement.

How can I prevent the Header from being deleted if it doesn't meet the criteria necessary. Example for Header table:

```
 Key      |  Status
 -------------------
 001      |  00
 002      |  00
 003      |  40
```

My Delete Statement:

```
 DELETE FROM HEADER WHERE KEY = '003'
```

In my DELETE TRIGGER before I delete the detail I'm checking to make sure the Status < 40. If this is not the case I throw an error, how can I do the same for the Header?

My Code is below:

```
 ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[trg_PO_DELETE]

 ON PO

 AFTER DELETE

 AS

DECLARE
    @Date                   DATETIME
    , @Who                  VARCHAR(20)
    , @ProcessedStatus      CHAR(2)
    , @ProcessingStatus     CHAR(2)
    , @ShmtType             INT
    , @POType               INT
    , @MsgNo                INT
    , @Msg                  VARCHAR(MAX)
    , @Continue             INT

SET @Date                   = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
SET @Who                    = SYSTEM_USER
SET @ProcessedStatus        = '90'
SET @ProcessingStatus       = '40'
SET @ShmtType               = 3
SET @POType                 = 1
SET @MsgNo                  = 0
SET @Msg                    = ''
SET @Continue               = 0



IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM PO(NOLOCK)
                JOIN DELETED ON PO.po_asn_number = DELETED.po_asn_number
                            AND PO.po_customer_id = DELETED.po_customer_id
                            AND PO.po_number = DELETED.po_number
                            AND PO.po_type = DELETED.po_type
                            AND PO.po_status = DELETED.po_status
            WHERE PO.po_status < @ProcessingStatus)
    BEGIN
        /*  REMOVE SHIPMENT DETAIL WHEN SHIPMENT HEADER IS DELETED  */
        DELETE PO_DETAIL
        FROM PO_DETAIL 
        JOIN DELETED ON PO_DETAIL.pd_asn_number = DELETED.po_asn_number
                    AND PO_DETAIL.pd_customer_id = DELETED.po_customer_id
                    AND PO_DETAIL.pd_po_number = DELETED.po_number
                    AND PO_DETAIL.pd_type = DELETED.po_type

        /*  REMOVE UCC FOR SHIPMENT WHEN SHIPMENT IS DELETED*/ 
        DELETE UCC
        FROM UCC
        JOIN DELETED ON UCC.cs_shipment_number = DELETED.po_asn_number
                    AND UCC.cs_po_number = DELETED.po_number
                    AND DELETED.po_type = @ShmtType

        /*  UPDATE PO LEVEL INFORMATION */
        UPDATE PO 
                SET PO.po_shipped_qty = PO.po_shipped_qty - DELETED.po_shipped_qty
                , PO.po_received_qty = PO.po_received_qty - DELETED.po_received_qty
        FROM PO
        JOIN DELETED ON PO.po_asn_number = DELETED.po_number
                    AND PO.po_number = DELETED.po_number
                    AND PO.po_customer_id = DELETED.po_customer_id
                    AND DELETED.po_type = @POType
    END
ELSE
    BEGIN
        SET @Continue = 1
        SET @MsgNo = 50000
        SET @Msg = dbo.fnc_GetMessage(@MsgNo)
    END
 IF @Continue=1  -- Error Occured
    BEGIN
      RAISERROR @MsgNo @Msg
      RETURN
    END
```

I think my issue is because the Header record is gone before I can do the join. Any help you may provide will be really helpful.

Comment: Wrap both in a Transaction and do a ROLLBACK if any errors are thrown. That's what Transactions are for.

Comment: Thank you. I'm adding transaction count along with the INSTEAD OF DELETE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the `INSTEAD OF DELETE` trigger, something like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER TEST1 
ON DBO.HEADER 
INSTEAD OF DELETE 
AS 
  BEGIN 
      DELETE H 
      FROM   HEADER H 
             INNER JOIN DELETED d 
                     ON H.[KEY] = d.[KEY] 
                        AND H.STATUS < 40 
  END 

GO
```